# How to stream audio in Gstreamer (Python)

Tags: ibm-cloud, gstreamer, ibm-watson, gstreamer-1.0, watson-text-to-speech

I am making a python application that takes text converts it into audio using ibm cloud Watson TTS, then return an audio using

```
content = watson_tts.synthesize(text, voice), accept=format).get_result().content
```

then I want to take this content and stream using Gstreamer, without saving it to a file.
I know how to play files from uri using this:

```
player = Gst.ElementFactory.make("playbin", "player")
player.set_property("uri", uri)
player.set_state(Gst.State.PLAYING)
```

but that's not what I want,
what I want is being able to stream the audio directly without downloading

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After executing

```
content = watson_tts.synthesize(text, voice), accept=format).get_result()
```

synthesized audio is already "downloaded" from IBM's service so instead of "what I want is being able to stream the audio directly without downloading" I suppose it's better to say "... without saving to a file".

Anyways... to "programmatically" feed gstreamer's pipeline with (audio) bytes from Python's `content` object, you can utilize [`appsrc`](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/app/appsrc.html?gi-language=python) element.

For example, the pipeline can be implemented something like this
[image]

and it will produce [MPEG Transport Stream](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MPEG_transport_stream) with `aac` encoded audio streamed via UDP.